# Acceleration + velocity calculus question

Tags: calculus, applications

Explanation for Calculus question needed
The acceleration $a\,\text{m/s}^2$ of a particle $P$ moving in a straight line is given by $a = 3(1-x^2)$ , where $x$ metres is the displacement of the particle to the right of the origin. Initially the particle is at the origin moving with a velocity of $4\,\text{m/s}$. Show that the velocity $v\,\text{m/s}$ of the particle is given by $v^2 = 16+6x-2x^3$.

Comment: Please include your own thoughts and efforts on the question.

Comment: I understand that acceleration is the integral of velocity, but why is it that when I integrate acceleration, it is 1/2 v^2

Comment: @Jessica Nguyen Velocity is the integral of acceleration with respect to time. In this problem we are given acceleration as a function of displacement. The integral of acceleration with respect to displacement is $\frac{1}{2}v^2$.

Comment: Questions are usually better-received here if you provide evidence of your own efforts and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 4):

we know that; $a=\frac{dv}{dt}$

$a= \frac{dv}{dt}\cdot\frac{dx}{dx}$

$a= \frac{dv}{dx}\cdot v$   $\qquad$as $\frac{dx}{dt} =v$

$a\cdot\,dx=v\cdot dv$

integrate on both sides;

$\int a\,dx=\int v\,dv$

$\int (3-3x^2)\,dx=\int v\,dv$

$3x-x^3+C = \frac{v^2}2$

$v^2 =6x-2x^3+C$

given thatat origin velocity is $4\,ms^{-1}$

$16=0+C$

$C=16$

therefore the equation is ;

$v^2=6x-2x^3+16$

Comment: This is the best answer (in my opinion). The relationship $a = v\frac{dv}{dx}$ (by chain rule) is very useful when finding the relationship between $v$ and $x$ independent of $t$. It's also a handy trick when proving the kinetic energy formula.

Answer (score 1):

Another try:

$\dfrac{dv}{dt} = a = 3(1-x^2).$

$\dfrac{dv}{dt}=\dfrac{dv}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{dt} =v\dfrac{dv}{dx};$

Hence:

$v\dfrac{dv}{dx}= 3(1-x^2).$

Separating variables:

$(v)dv = 3(1-x^2)dx$.

Integrating:

$(1/2)v^2 =3x - x^3 +C;$

For $x=0$: $v (x=0) =4$.

$C= (1/2)(16) =8.$

Finally :

$v^2= 6x -2x^3 +16.$

Comment: And this is different from @pranavB23's answer how?

Comment: Deepak.Quite similar. That's why you down voted, that's  ok.

Answer (score 0):

You have a differential equation $$\ddot{x}=3(1-\frac{1}{x^2})$$

You have initial conditions:

$$\begin{equation}
  x(0)=0 \\
  \dot{x}(0)=4
\end{equation}$$

Now you only need to solve it and then invert the relation between *t* and *x* to obtain speed at each coordinate.

Comment: It is possible to solve this more simply using a first order d.e. approach as in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since $F=ma$ we know that the force acting on the particle as a function of its mass $m$ and its displacement $x$ is

$F=m(3-3x^2)$

We also know that the change in energy of the particle is the integral of force with respect to distance, so

$E(x) - E(0) = \int_{0}^x m(3-3x^2) dx = m(3x - x^3)$

where $E(x)$ is the energy of the particle at displacement $x$. But this energy is all kinetic energy (no other forms of energy are mentioned in the question) so

$E(x) = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$

and, since we know that $v=4$ when $x=0$, we also have

$E(0) = 8m$

Now you have everything you need to solve the question.

(Update: the comments below are correct - the purely kinematic approach is simpler and does not require the assumption of constant mass)

Comment: This is quite unnecessary as a purely kinematic approach works fine and is much simpler.

Comment: @Deepak Do you mean that one from paranavB23's answer? But it's mostly the same. Note that he calculates kinetic energy as $$\int v \mathrm{dv}$$.

Comment: @gandalf61 You don't need mass here.

Comment: @bipll Yes I mean the other answer. He calculates $\int vdv$, but doesn't equate it to the ratio $\frac Em$, because that sort of thing is really unnecessary here.

Comment: @bipll By the way, that's only *equal* to the kinetic energy for a unit mass (which this cannot be assumed to be). Otherwise, it's $\frac Em$, as I mentioned. In any case, all this is not worth bothering with, as I said.

Comment: No, it's unitless.